# Hibernate - Traversing createSQLQuery results and reading into appropriate object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am pretty new to Hibernate / Java (JSF 2.0) and I am attempting to call a custom query and read the results into an object that I have created Logins. Logins has two setter functions, setLoginDate(Date date) and setUserId(Integer userId)  my function looks like so, The issue I am having is how to transform the result set and read in the appropriate values into a temp loginList

```
public List<Logins> getUserLogins() {

     Session session = getSessionFactory().openSession();
     List<Logins> loginList = null;
     Login temp = null;

     try {

         String SQL_QUERY = "SELECT login_date, user_id FROM user_logins";
         Query query = session.createSQLQuery(SQL_QUERY);

         List results = query.list();
         for(ListIterator iter = results.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {

              ** THIS IS THE PART I AM NOT CLEAR ON ***
              temp.setLoginDate(resutls.get(0));
              temp.setUserId(results.get(1));

              loginList.add(temp);
              temp = null;

              *****************************************

              return loginList;
         }

     } catch(HibernateException e) {
         throw new PersistanceDaoException(e);
     } finally {
         session.close();
     }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

missing part:

```
      Object[] row = (Object[]) iter.next();
      temp = new Login();
      temp.setLoginDate(row[0]);
      temp.setUserId(row[1]);
```

you may need to cast `row[i]` to your target object for example if login date is a date object: `temp.setLoginDate((Date) row[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

for a better solution, try to use `ResultTransformer` 
you can find more about ResultTransformer in Hibernate Docs.

Comment: Awesome!  Actually I like the first answer better, it was what I was looking for (I wanted the actual values not to translate to another *&#$&*^$ hibernate object)